# ms graph php sdk message object fails to check if there are attachments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am retrieving messages from an Outlook account.  I am trying to get inline files and attachments from those messages.

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($this->getAccessToken());

$messageQueryParams = array (
    "\$select" => "subject,receivedDateTime,from,sentDateTime,body,toRecipients,sender,uniqueBody,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,attachments",
    "\$orderby" => "receivedDateTime DESC",
    "\$top" => "200" 
);

$url = '/me/mailfolders/' . $folder . '/messages/delta';
$url_combiner = '?';

$getMessagesUrl = $url . $url_combiner . http_build_query($messageQueryParams);
$response = $graph->createRequest('GET', $getMessagesUrl)->execute();

$messages = $response->getResponseAsObject( \Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message::class );

foreach($messages as $msg) {
     echo $msg->getHasAttachments();
}
```

This code returns 'null' for $msg->getHasAttachments();  I would expect it to return a true or false.

The messages I am downloading from this folder have both inline attachments and mail attachments, so I am looking for a solution to both.

(Responses that point to specific points in the MS Graph PHP SDK documentation are very appreciated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, in your case `getHasAttachments()` method returns `null` since `hasAttachments` is not included in `$select` query option and therefore *it is not requested from a server*. It needs to be explicitly included, for example:

```
$messageQueryParams = array (
    "\$select" => "hasAttachments,...",
    //another params are omitted for clarity
);
```

Then whether a message contains attachments or not could be determined like this:

```
foreach($messages as $msg) {
    if($msg->getHasAttachments() == true){
        //...
}
```

There is one more issue with the provided example, to retrieve `Message.attachments` *reference property* (or relationship property) it needs to be specified via `$expand` query string parameter instead of `$select` (refer [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter) for a more details), like this:

```
$messageQueryParams = array (
     "\$expand" => "attachments",
    //another params are omitted for clarity
);
```

Then attachments collection could be iterated like this:

```
 foreach($messages as $msg) {
    foreach($msg->getAttachments() as $attachment) {
        //...
    }
 }
```